# Have I ever done you wrong before?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Have I ever done you wrong before?

Can someone please explain what exactly this sentence means?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "do someone wrong" means to treat someone in an unfair way. Hence, he asks somebody if he has ever mistreated them.